# email address not recognised in XML-RPC interface to Neos Server

Tags: python-2.7, neos-server

I am using the XML-RPC submission API to the Neos Server (optimization, AMPL, MILP, Cplex) and am receiving an error message to say that "CPLEX will not run unless you provide a valid email address."

Am I misinterpreting what I should do with the provided python template found on the Neos site[here] and [here](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/NEOS-API.html)?

The relevant snippet of the Neos-provided .py [file](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/NeosClient.py) that I edited is below

```
import sys
import xmlrpclib
import time

NEOS_HOST="www.neos-server.org"
NEOS_PORT=3332
CONTACT_EMAIL = 'me@mail.com'
INTERFACE = 'XML-RPC'
neos=xmlrpclib.Server("http://%s:%d" % (NEOS_HOST, NEOS_PORT))
...
(jobNumber, password) = neos.submitJob(xml, CONTACT_EMAIL, INTERFACE)
sys.stdout.write("JobNumber = %d \n" % jobNumber)
```

Besides the email error, my code works. I know because sometimes other solvers will return a result (it seems some solvers - though not CPLEX - don't require an email address)

**An unrelated question**
For folks who are using this Neos server interface, what are the alternatives to using regex to parse the returned output file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Neos server team responded :

Add your email address into the xml that you are submitting. In your xml, add a line

```
<email> your.address@email.edu </email>
```

along with the fields like

```
<model></model>
<data></data>
```

etc